# Bitmap(Compress/Text/Save)

Tags: android, c#, bitmap, mono, xamarin

Я использую API камеры android для того, чтобы сделать фото, затем мне нужно добавить на сделанную фотографию (поверх нее) определенный текст и прямоугольник (в котором будет тот самый текст). Затем необходимо сохранить готовое фото (с добавленным текстом и прямоугольником) в память телефона.

Я использовал следующее:

1. Вызываю API камеры
2. После положительного результата(нажата
   кнопка ОК),возвращаюсь в метод OnActivityResult,в котором буду
   вызывать:
   Метод, который конвертирует фотографию в битмап (для того чтобы добавить текст\прямоугольник). Затем вызываю метод,который добавляет текст\прямоугольник (через Paint\Canvas). После этих манипуляций, завершением идет вызов метода BitmapCompress, благодаря которому я сохраняю готовое изображение со всеми плюшками.

Проблема заключается в том, что функция Compress загружает изображение (полностью) в оперативную память телефона, и, более того, процесс сохранения не очень быстрый (примерно от 2 до 4 секунд). Если я буду делать несколько фотографий, то приложение "упадёт" с OutOfMemoryException.

Я сделал кое-какой обход, который категорически мне не нравится (наихудший вариант):

1. использую асинхронно тот самый Compress (не блокируется поток
   UI, что уже более не менее).
2. по завершению компрессирования вызываю Bitmap.Recycle() для того, чтобы удалить из памяти.

В любом случае это решение меня не устраивает (да и не особо помогает), ибо асинхронный компресс не блокирует UI, но мне необходимо получить готовое изображение сразу же после того как я сделал снимок. А также вызов Bitmap.Recycle() работает как-то коряво, мало того что GC помимо самой компресии жрет ресурсы, так еще и не совсем корректно освобождает из памяти битмап.

PS Еще присутствует баг с прорисовкой текста через **Canvas**, а именно - он рисуется почему-то вертикально (а должен горизонтально).

Comment: Я не спец по андроиду, но почему бы не сделать так: (1) завести очередь операций обработки; (2) после взятия снимка добавить её в очередь и показывать фотографию пока как есть (может быть со специальным значком «на обработке»; (3) очередь заданий обрабатывать вне UI-потока по одному; (4) когда фото обработано, если оно ещё на экране, обновить его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну во-первых все долгие операции необходимо обрабатывать ассинхронно. Особенно, что касается работы с сетью и ФС.

Второе, фриз UI потока вообще дурной тон, и его следует избегать, во что бы то ни стало. Что бы блокировать UI пользователя нужно воспользоваться диалогом. В котором кстати, можно установить прогресс в случае обработки нескольких снимков.

Если Вы не хотите, что бы, при сворачивании приложения, операция обработки изображения падало, необходимо её запускать через сервис.

Bitmap удалить можно вызовом Dispose(). Так же Bitmap можно обернуть в using. По завершении выполнения блока, эта конструкция гарантирует очищение памяти.